# Swtich project teams in TFS 2017 portal

Tags: tfs

I have got TFS 2017 on prem and have created an additional team with it's own area. I have then added a new user story for both of these areas/teams.

I am a member of both of the areas, but can't see a way to switch between the two teams.

When looking at the backlog I can only see one of the user stories. How can I then switch to the other team and see other stories associated with that area?

In addition, I can't see a way of seeing what teams I belong to in a project without going into the settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking along the lines of a new user coming along to view the project teams and so the teams wouldn't be in the Recent list. I found the list is at the Team Project list, it just needs to be expanded:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to several features depend on the team project or team that you have selected. For example, dashboards, backlogs, and board views will change depending on the context selected. How to select team based on your detail TFS version, such as:

> Open the team project/team drop-down menu and select the team
>   project/team that you've recently visited. If you don't see the team
>   or team project you want, choose Browse all to **browse all** team
>   projects and teams.

[image]

If you are using TFS2017 update1, to switch your team focus to a team project or team you've recently viewed, hover over the **Team Services icon**  and choose from the drop-down menu of options.

[image]

For more detail info please refer the tutorial in MSDN--**[Switch team project or team focus](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/work-web-portal#team-scoped-features)**

Comment: Thanks for that, but that is only relevant if you have previously viewed the teams. I was trying to find a way to list them if (for example) you've just been given permission and so have never looked at it before. I've found the list was actually just the Team Projects needed expanding (see my answer).

Comment: Yes @ADringer ,this is the fastest way to switch team, just like a bookmark. However I also mentioned  `If you don't see the team or team project you want, choose Browse all to browse all team projects and teams.` above .The teams are under the project. This will give you what you need. Just the same result as your screenshot below.